# Verificar contraseña si tiene más de dos mayúsculas en Java

Tags: java, contraseña

le explico estoy haciendo un programa en donde cuando se crea la contraseña, si tiene más de 2 mayúsculas es fuerte, en caso contrario, es débil

```
String Contrasenia;
int contador;

public void esFuerte() {
    Contrasenia="";
    Random aleatorio= new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if(i<4) 
            Contrasenia+=aleatorio.nextInt(10);

        else 
            Contrasenia+=(char)(aleatorio.nextInt(91)+65);

    for(int j=0; j<8;j++) {

        char caracter= Contrasenia.charAt(j);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(caracter))
            contador+=1;
        }
    if(contador==2)
        System.out.println("La contaseña es fuerte");

    else
        System.out.println("La contraseña es débil");
    }
}
```

este es mi código del programa y lo siguiente es el main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Password alfanumerico= new Password();
    alfanumerico.esFuerte();
}
```

pero resulta que me aparecen los siguientes errores

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Password.esFuerte(Password.java:20)
    at Main4.main(Main4.java:6)

Espero que me puedan ayudar, ya que es una guía de ejercicios y sinceramente es el único que se me ha complicado, espero de su ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Tu código asume que la contraseña que te pasan tendrá siempre al menos 8 letras. Si es más corta, lanzará la excepción. En caso de que un código te lance una excepción, deberías buscarla en la documentación de Java ya que te explicará qué significa ese error.

Answer (score 1):

IndexOutOfBounds significa que se salio del rango es decir estar tratando de llegar a la posicion 8 y tu array es de 7 o estas tratando de llegar al 9 y tu array es de 8.

Comment: si...eso mismo estaba pensando, pero no estaba bien seguro, gracia por responder :)

Answer (score 0):

El error que te daba era al recorrer la contraseña una vez establecida. Basta con que el bucle se ejecute mientras *j* sea menor a la longitud de la variable contraseña.
También te he cambiado los dos bucles for, tenías anidado el segundo en el primero; y las comprobaciones finales las he dejado fuera, sino se repetían continuamente los mensajes.

```
package stackOverFlow;
import java.util.Random;

public class Password {

private String contraseña;
private int contador;

public void esFuerte() {
    contraseña="";
    Random aleatorio= new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if(i<4) 
            contraseña+=aleatorio.nextInt(10);

        else 
            contraseña+=(char)(aleatorio.nextInt(91)+65);
    }

    for(int j=0; j<contraseña.length();j++) {

        char caracter= contraseña.charAt(j);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(caracter)) contador+=1;
    }

    if(contador==2)
        System.out.println("La contaseña es fuerte");

    else
        System.out.println("La contraseña es débil");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Password().esFuerte();
}
```

}

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias estimado, debe ser que a veces tengo la mala costumbre de no usar las {} cuando se trata de 1 sola instrucciones (ya que se puede obviar), pero lo mejor es usarlas para no dejar confusiones, saludos